# How to loop through a csv file and only when it encountered a specific word save it into a list?

Tags: python, web-scraping, data-cleaning

I want to loop through this csv that has country, data, and a number I need to extract. The file  looks like this:

> b'/*O_o*/\ngoogle.visualization.Query.setResponse({"version":"0.6","reqId":"0output=csv","status":"ok","sig":"1241529276","table":{"cols":[{"id":"A","label":"Entity","type":"string"},{"id":"B","label":"Week","type":"number","pattern":"General"},{"id":"C","label":"Day","type":"date","pattern":"yyyy-mm-dd"},{"id":"D","label":"Flights
> 2019
> (Reference)","type":"number","pattern":"General"},{"id":"E","label":"Flights","type":"number","pattern":"General"},{"id":"F","label":"%
> vs 2019
> (Daily)","type":"number","pattern":"General"},{"id":"G","label":"Flights
> (7-day moving
> average)","type":"number","pattern":"General"},{"id":"H","label":"% vs
> 2019 (7-day Moving
> Average)","type":"number","pattern":"General"},{"id":"I","label":"Day
> 2019","type":"date","pattern":"yyyy-mm-dd"},{"id":"J","label":"Day
> Previous
> Year","type":"date","pattern":"yyyy-mm-dd"},{"id":"K","label":"Flights
> Previous
> Year","type":"number","pattern":"General"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"Albania"},{"v":36.0,"f":"36"},{"v":"Date(2020,8,1)","f":"2020-09-01"},{"v":129.0,"f":"129"},{"v":64.0,"f":"64"},{"v":-0.503875968992248,"f":"-0,503875969"},{"v":71.5714285714286,"f":"71,57142857"},{"v":-0.291371994342291,"f":"-0,2913719943"},{"v":"Date(2019,8,3)","f":"2019-09-03"},{"v":"Date(2019,8,3)","f":"2019-09-03"},{"v":129.0,"f":"129"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Albania"},{"v":36.0,"f":"36"},{"v":"Date(2020,8,2)","f":"2020-09-02"},{"v":92.0,"f":"92"},{"v":59.0,"f":"59"},{"v":-0.358695652173913,"f":"-0,3586956522"},{"v":70.0,"f":"70"},{"v":-0.300998573466476,"f":"-0,3009985735"},{"v":"Date(2019,8,4)","f":"2019-09-04"},{"v":"Date(2019,8,4)","f":"2019-09-04"},{"v":92.0,"f":"92"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Albania"},{"v":36.0,"f":"36"},{"v":"Date(2020,8,3)","f":"2020-09-03"},{"v":96.0,"f":"96"},{"v":67.0,"f":"67"},{"v":-0.302083333333333,"f":"-0,3020833333"},{"v":70.1428571428571,"f":"70,14285714"},{"v":-0.30354609929078,"f":"-0,3035460993"},{"v":"Date(2019,8,5)","f":"2019-09-05"},{"v":"Date(2019,8,5)","f":"2019-09-05"},{"v":96.0,"f":"96"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Albania"},{"v":36.0,"f":"36"},{"v":"Date(2020,8,4)","f":"2020-09-04"},{"v":103.0,"f":"103"},{"v":89.0,"f":"89"},{"v":-0.135922330097087,"f":"-0,1359223301"},{"v":69.2857142857143,"f":"69,28571429"},{"v":-0.312056737588652,"f":"-0,3120567376"},{"v":"Date(2019,8,6)","f":"2019-09-06"},{"v":"Date(2019,8,6)","f":"2019-09-06"},{"v":103.0,"f":"103"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Albania"},{"v":36.0,"f":"36"},{"v":"Date(2020,8,5)","f":"2020-09-05"},{"v":94.0,"f":"94"},{"v":53.0,"f":"53"},{"v":-0.436170212765957,"f":"-0,4361702128"},{"v":68.8571428571429,"f":"68,85714286"},{"v":-0.314366998577525,"f":"-0,3143669986"},{"v":"Date(2019,8,7)","f":"2019-09-07"},{"v":"Date(2019,8,7)","f":"2019-09-07"},{"v":94.0,"f":"94"}]}, ...

In there it says Albania, which is a country with data I need to extract. For example:

> {"c":[{"v":"Albania"},{"v":36.0,"f":"36"},{"v":"Date(2020,8,4)","f":"2020-09-04"},{"v":103.0,"f":"103"},{"v":89.0,"f":"89"},{"v":-0.135922330097087,"f":"-0,1359223301"},{"v":69.2857142857143,"f":"69,28571429"},{"v":-0.312056737588652,"f":"-0,3120567376"},{"v":"Date(2019,8,6)","f":"2019-09-06"},{"v":"Date(2019,8,6)","f":"2019-09-06"},{"v":103.0,"f":"103"}]}

How would I write a python script to loop over the entire csv file and find every occurrence of the word "Albania", save it, then go a little further and get the date "2020-09-04", and then get the number -0.1359?

Comment: Do you have any code to show what have you tried and what's not working? we are here to help resolve problems, not to provide solutions ;)

Comment: I would recommend different kind of formatting then the one you have shown.

Comment: What's shown in your question is _not_ in csv format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read this using `json`.

```
import json

with open('txtfile1.txt') as input:
    data = input.read()
#Select the part where the dictionary start (after "rows":)
nesteddict = json.loads(data[(data.find('rows')+6):])
finallist = []
for x in nesteddict:
    sublist = []
    sublist.append(x['c'][0]['v'])
    sublist.append(x['c'][2]['f'])
    sublist.append(x['c'][5]['v'])
    finallist.append(sublist)
```

This will output

```
[['Albania', '2020-09-01', -0.503875968992248], ['Albania', '2020-09-02', -0.358695652173913], ['Albania', '2020-09-03', -0.302083333333333], ['Albania', '2020-09-04', -0.135922330097087], ['Albania', '2020-09-05', -0.436170212765957]]
```